# How to write a script (for Windows XP) to run a python program?

Tags: python, windows-xp

Basically, I'd like to run a script (versus typing python program.py) or even have a shortcut that I could click on and start the program. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried double-clicking the *.py file?

Comment: When you double-clicked the *.py file, what did it do?  When you typed the name of your *.py file in the command window, what did it do?  What have you tried?

Comment: Why this question has a +1? (not this one, the one from the OP)

Answer (score 2):

From [python.org](http://www.python.org/doc//current/tutorial/interpreter.html#the-interpreter-and-its-environment):

> On Windows systems, there is no
>   notion of an “executable mode”. The
>   Python installer automatically
>   associates `.py` files with python.exe
>   so that a double-click on a Python
>   file will run it as a script. The
>   extension can also be `.pyw`, in that
>   case, the console window that normally
>   appears is suppressed.

Also from [python.org](http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable):

> On Windows 2000, the standard Python
>   installer already associates the .py
>   extension with a file type
>   (Python.File) and gives that file type
>   an open command that runs the
>   interpreter (`D:\Program
>   Files\Python\python.exe "%1" %*`). This
>   is enough to make scripts executable
>   from the command prompt as `‘foo.py’`.
>   If you’d rather be able to execute the
>   script by simple typing `‘foo’` with no
>   extension you need to add `.py` to the
>   `PATHEXT` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [batch](http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm) file (.bat).

Type in whatever commands you want to execute in the proper order, in notepad, such as:

```
python program.py
```

Save the file as iHateTyping.bat

Open the command prompt using `Run`.

Go to the directory where you saved the file using `cd`.

Type in:

```
iHateTyping.bat
```

& you're done.

I encourage you to read more about batch files in the link highlighted above.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then type `python.py` to run your Python script.

Answer (score -1):

Use `py2exe` to create a portable windows executable file.